# Android - Remove top banner in new application?

Tags: android

Is there a way to remove the banner that appears at the top of my new Android application that has the application name in it? I think I need to do something in the AndroidManifest.xml file, but I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is actually in the [Common Tasks and How to Do Them under the section "Configuring General Window Properties."](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#configurewindowproperties)

*[update]* as per the comments

Either call...

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Or add the following to your Android manifest file...

`<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">`

Comment: In short, either call `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` in the `onCreate()` lifecycle method, or define this globally by using a theme without the title by appending the following attribute to your `<application>` tag in the AndroidManifest.xml: `android:theme="android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`.

Comment: Correct, I just found it easier to refer to that link and propograte the good documentation.

Comment: This should be:

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`

You missed the the at the rate symbol.

Answer (score 3):

In file Style.xml:

(App--->src--->main--->res->values--->styles.xml) changes the **< resources>** to :

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

    </style>

</resources>
```